# PHP - Uploading image with thumbnail that has max width and height

Tags: php, image, file, upload, resize

I would like to upload an image and have a thumbnail version of it with max width of 150 px and max height of 400 px and saved as thumbnail-filename

```
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
$errors= array();
$file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
$file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];  
$tempext =  explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name']);
$file_ext=strtolower(end($tempext));
$extensions = array("jpeg","jpg","png","gif","");       
if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions )=== false){
 $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a different file.";
}
if($file_size > 419430400){
$errors[]='Maximum file size is 400mb';
}               
if(empty($errors)==true){
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"../large_format/a0/".$file_name);
    echo '<script>function myFunction(){alert("Success!");} myFunction();</script>';
}else{
    print_r($errors);
}
```

so there would be a large image file and a thumbnail version of it.
I would really appreciate an example of suggested codes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try `getimagesize()` function [Link](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.getimagesize.php).

```
//upload orginal size photo     
    // Capture the original size of the uploaded image
            list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);
                if ($width > 150){
                    $newwidth=150;
                    $newheight=($height/$width)*600;
                }else{
                                $newwidth=$width;
                 }
                if($height>400)
                 {
                     $newheight=400

                 }
                 else {
                    $newheight=$height;
                  }

            $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

You do not need to alter these functions

```
function resizeImage($image,$width,$height,$scale) {
    list($imagewidth, $imageheight, $imageType) = getimagesize($image);
    $imageType = image_type_to_mime_type($imageType);
    $newImageWidth = ceil($width * $scale);
    $newImageHeight = ceil($height * $scale);
    $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newImageWidth,$newImageHeight);
    switch($imageType) {
        case "image/gif":$source=imagecreatefromgif($image); break;
        case "image/pjpeg":
        case "image/jpeg":
        case "image/jpg":$source=imagecreatefromjpeg($image);break;
        case "image/png":
        case "image/x-png":$source=imagecreatefrompng($image); break;
    }
    $size_fit=$_SESSION['size_fit'];
    if($size_fit==1){
    if ($width > 140){
                $newwidth=140;
                $newheight=($height/$width)*140;
            }else {$newwidth=$width;
                $newheight=$height;}
    imagecopyresampled($newImage,$source,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);
    }else{
    imagecopyresampled($newImage,$source,0,0,0,0,$newImageWidth,$newImageHeight,$width,$height);
    }
    switch($imageType) {
        case "image/gif":imagegif($newImage,$image); break;
        case "image/pjpeg":
        case "image/jpeg":
        case "image/jpg":imagejpeg($newImage,$image,90);break;
        case "image/png":
        case "image/x-png":imagepng($newImage,$image); break;
    }
    chmod($image, 0777);
    return $image;
}
```

Comment: Hi Shibu Thomas. can you tell me how to use this?